# How to load file in SageMath 7.1

Tags: sage

I am new to Sage & I wish to load a `.sage` file from a `Sage Notebook worksheet`.
I am on `OSX 10.9.5`.

If I evaluate 
load `(example.sage)`
I get

> IOError: did not find file 'example.sage' to load or attach

The example file is on my Desktop.

Do I need to explicitly state the full file path?
If so how?
Thx.

Comment: I would highly recommend upgrading to a more recent version of macOS. Older versions no longer receive security updates, and are vulnerable to many attacks.

Comment: I would recommend installing a more recent version of SageMath. SageMath keeps improving, so more recent versions have less bugs and more features!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to load that file located on your desktop.

One way is using `~` to denote your home directory:

```
load('~/Desktop/example.sage')
```

The other one is to use the full path:

```
load('/Users/username/Desktop/example.sage')
```

(replacing `username` by your actual username).